# how to create dynamic value to id attributes of a element in my jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

In my jsp page i am creating multiple elements dynamically. and i want to give unique id to the created elements. The need of using Id in this problem is as follows, if am creating 2 elements in the page, each element will get sub menu on hover.The sub menu will also generated dynamically, so that generated submenu should go to their respective windows. to work this i want to know their ids and also that should be unique.

Comment: @JasonP actually i have done this with some random value which is coming from my controller to jsp page, but some times am getting duplicate values and the elements are creating with duplicate ids the issue with this is when am trying to put the values to a particular id it is going to the first div. so to avoid this i want a function which should generate random value in jsp page on every call.

Comment: Sounds like you need not necessarily a random number, but a unique number. Sounds like you could just keep a counter, increment it for each element, and append that to the end of some string to get the id for that element. If you posted some code, it might paint a clearer picture of what you need.